# Is it possible to restrict the scope of an event I would like to listen for? From a certain component for example?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have two p:dataTable elements on my page. I would like to have an ajax element listening for the rowSelectRadio event on each datatable, seperately.  The issue is that these listeners are capturing the rowSelectRadio event from both tables.  Is there any way to restrict the scope of the event for which I am listening?  I guess I assumed that an ajax element would only listen within the scope of its parent component, but this does not seem to be the case.

Here is an example:  I would like for the rowSelectRadio event to be caught only by the ajax element that is a child of the specific datatable.

```
<p:panel id="parentPanel">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable1" >
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio"
    listener="#{myBean.onData1RowSelect}"
    update="parentPanel"/>
        <p:column/>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dataTable id="dataTable2" >
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio"
    listener="#{myBean.onData2RowSelect}"
    update="parentPanel"/>
        <p:column/>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) of your actual code to have better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `process` attribut to your `p:ajax` :

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable2" >
<p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio"
    listener="#{myBean.onData2RowSelect}"
    update="dataTable2" process="@this" />
    <p:column/>
</p:dataTable>
```

**See** :
[PPR - Partial Tree Process](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf)

Comment: I tried adding the process attribute to the ajax elements, but I am still seeing the onData2RowSelect method fire when I select a row of the first datatable.

Comment: I realized that my example is not quite accurate however.  My update is actually pointing at a container that holds both datatables.  Could this be overriding my process attribute?

Comment: I tried scaling down my update attribute to point specifically at the elements that I needed.  That seems to have done the trick.  Your solution definitely led me to the answer, so thanks.